# Stop `cp -al` trying to link to hidden files?

Tags: cp, hard-link

I would like to make a "hard-links" copy of my home directory before syncing my home directory with another computer with unison, just in case unison goes awry.

But `cp -al` tries to link to *all* files, including hidden . files, which results in many errors. I am not trying to sync . hidden files or any "system" files, just my own data.

Is there any way to make cp -al ignore . hidden files? Or another command that has `cp -al` functionality that can be made to ignore . hidden files?

Answer (score 0):

It is usually enough to skip hidden files and hidden directories at the first level in the home directory, and then the following command should work,

```
cp -avl "$HOME"/* outputdir
```

The wild card, `*`, will not select hidden files and hidden directories for copying. The option `v` will show which files are copied (useful while testing).

---

Please remember that hard links work only within the same partition and only for files. You need symbolic links across partitions and for directories.

So `cp` *copies* the directories to new inodes and *hardlinks* the files to the same inode as the corresponding source file.

Comment: Thank you...close, but doesn't quite do it. Firstly I am trying to make a hardlink copy of /home not /home/user (there are several users), but I can probably get around this with a for loop for the first level, and then using your suggestion for the remainder ie. each user. But secondly, one of the users needs a snap app and there are several . files within the user snap directory that causes `cp -al` to throw errors. But I will see if I can find a non-snap alternative, I would quite like to get rid of snap for various other reasons.

Comment: @B.Tanner, drive space is fairly cheap nowadays. Maybe a safer and also easier option for you would be to use `rsync` and simply copy the home directory tree. You can copy everything, or limit the copying with `--exclude` or more advanced with `--filter`.

Comment: @B.Tanner, The following command line will exclude all hidden files and directories, even at lower levels: `sudo rsync -Havn --exclude=.* . /tmp`; You need `sudo` to manage several user's home directories. But `rsync` makes copies, not hardlinks, so this is a workaround, not a direct answer to your question.